# collectionオブジェクトについて

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel を学習中の者です。
以下のコードにつきまして、お聞きしたい部分があります。
以下はビュー部分の `index.blade.php` です

```
@extends('layouts.helloapp')

@section('title','Person.index')

@section('menubar')
  @parent
  インデックスページ

@endsection

@section('content')
  <table>
    <tr><th>Data</th></tr>
    @foreach ($items as $item)

      <tr>
        <td>{{$item}}</td>
        <td>{{$item->getData()}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
@endsection

@section('footer')
copyright 2017 tuyano.
@endsection
```

以下は、モデルクラスである `Person.php` です

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{   
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->id . ':' . $this->name . '(' . $this->age . ')';
    }

}
```

以下はコントローラー部分である、 `PersonController.php` です

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Person;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Person::all();
        // if($items instanceof Person){
        //     die('ok');
        // }else{
        //     die('ng');
        // }

        // var_dump(get_object_vars($items));
        // exit();
        return view('person.index',['items' => $items]);

    }
}
```

以下はルート部分である、 `web.php` です。

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


// Route::post('hello','HelloContoroller@post');

//use App\Http\Middleware\HelloMiddleware;

Route::get('hello/add','HelloController@add');
Route::post('hello/add','HelloController@create');

Route::get('hello','HelloController@index');

Route::get('hello/edit','HelloController@edit');
Route::post('hello/edit','HelloController@update');

Route::get('hello/del','HelloController@del');
Route::post('hello/del','HelloController@remove');
Route::get('hello/show','HelloController@show');
Route::get('person','PersonController@index');
Route::get('test','HelloController@foo');
```

上記 `http://localhost/person` にアクセスすると、以下の画面が表示されます。

[image]

お聞きしたい部分なのですが、 `index.blade.php` 内の「`$item`」が何故 `getData` メソッドを呼び出せるのか、といった点です。

`PersonControler.php` 内で `var_dump` などし `$items` の中身を確認したのですが、 `getData` メソッドは存在していませんでした。
何故、 `getData` メソッドを呼び出すことができるのでしょうか？

Comment: 編集して頂きありがとうございます。
実は、コードブロックを使ってみたのですが、何故かコードがブロックの中に全部入らなくて...
助かりました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/192612

Comment: teratailの方で回答が得られなかった為、こちらにも投稿させて貰いました。